# Data Cleansing in Kylo

Tags: bigdata, teradata, kylo

I wanted to know if there are any methods to do data cleansing in Kylo (https://kylo.io/). I was able to get the tool to point out errors using data validation rules, but I was curious to know if it can also perform other functions. Examples:

- Deleting any empty records in between the data
- Detecting and deleting duplicate columns in the data

Answer (score 0):

Data cleansing is handled in Kylo using standardizers and validators. However, as of Kylo 0.9.0 there's no built-in functions for removing empty rows or duplicate columns. The current functions are limited to removing rows if a specific column is empty and removing duplicate rows.

This functionality could be added by writing a plugin:
http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer-guides/PluginApiIndex.html